# Page we need to choose to override for Custom User Registration in Liferay 6.1 among these two?

Tags: liferay-6

I am in need of  override the User registeration page inside the Liferay .
My requirement is that i need to add a Password and password confrmation field to it to the newly created user .
Before creating a hook to modify the jsp and the UserLocalService , i have got a below query

I have seen two user registration screens which are

1. a screen popped up when navigated through **Sign -In ---->Create_account Page**
2. **Control Panel ---> User and Organization ---> Add User Page**

Could anybody please let me know what is the page i need to choose from the above two ??

Also please let me know what is the difference between these two screens ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1  is for scenario when any guest user comes to your site and do registration.

Option 2 is screen where admin user creates user.

For user registration customization, you have to override create_account.jsp from sign in portlet.(option 1)